# What is difference between "&&" and "&" in styling techniques for "styled-components"?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I tried to make changes to the following code. I changed '&&' to '&' in LabelText styling. but I don't know, for example, why the first label is "blue" in the output when the input(Arman) is checked. while it is expected to be "red". perhaps, because I don't know the difference between the single ampersand and double ampersand (**'&&' v &'**), exactly.

In the [styled-components docs](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics) said '&' refers to **all instances** of the components, and '&&' refers to **an instance** of the component.

What is really the difference between these?

code:

```
const Arman = styled.input.attrs({ type: "checkbox" })``;

const Label = styled.label`
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  gap: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
`

const LabelText = styled.span`
  ${(props) => {
    switch (props.$mode) {
      case "dark":
        return css`
          background-color: black;
          color: white;
          ${Arman}:checked + & {
            color: blue;
          }
        `;
      default:
        return css`
          background-color: white;
          color: black;
          ${Arman}:checked + & {
            color: red;
          }
        `;
    }
  }}
`;

render(
  <React.Fragment>
    <Label>
      <Arman defaultChecked />
      <LabelText>Foo</LabelText>
    </Label>
    <Label>
      <Arman />
      <LabelText $mode="dark">Foo</LabelText>
    </Label>
    <Label>
      <Arman defaultChecked />
      <LabelText>Foo</LabelText>
    </Label>
    <Label>
      <Arman defaultChecked />
      <LabelText $mode="dark">Foo</LabelText>
    </Label>
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to5fs.png)

Comment: Where are you using `&&` in `styled-components`?

Comment: @HimanshuSingh In the above code, in both [ ${Arman}:checked + & ], first, '&&' was instead '&'. I changed that to '&'. but output is unexpexted.

Comment: I guess, this means that, if the `input` is `checked`, then `color` current component as `red`. Like in `logical operator &&`, both values need to be true, similarly, here, `${Arman}:checked + && { color: red; }`, then other `{color: red;}` being the string, is always `true`, thus the style is applied.

Comment: @HimanshuSingh I think don't understand your comment. here, '&' or '&&' refers to instance of 'LabelText', and this not  to mean logical operator &&. as far as I know, that's mean, color of 'LabelText' immediately after of that should be 'red' or 'blue', based on switch, when input is checked. here since first 'LabelText' not have a $mode prop, that's color should be 'red' but in output is 'blue'.

Comment: Yes right, I misunderstood the comment.

Answer (score 3):

The reason we use 2 ampersands is because specificity matters. Sometimes an existing class, such as that from Bootstrap, might have a lot of specificity. Using && applies the style to the component twice, and this is often enough to override what already exists in the class being overridden.

Comment: https://medium.com/@personnamedmike/react-styled-components-a-basic-guide-2e03c7bbbfcd

Comment: It doesn't apply it twice it literally selects the classname twice, you can inspect that, it ends up being `.myClass.myClass {...} `